# Catch print output

Tags: python, opencv

I’m using opencv and there is a call for video frame reading with VideoCapture and there is print statement automatically printing errors and information on console , and I want to catch these outputs and save to a file ..

VideoCapture is not returning this statements it’s just directly printing

How do I do that ?

Comment: You could just redirect all of `stderr` to a file, using `./yourprogram 2>logfile`. Another way would be to connect `sys.stderr` to a file, like `sys.stderr = open("logfile", 'w')`, or even better using a context-manager using `with`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to "hack" Python's print function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49271750/is-it-possible-to-hack-pythons-print-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if its the best way to do this but it will work.

You can read in everything your program prints into the console by typing this:

Here we print `print("test-test-test-test")` into the console, like `opencv` does it, and with `p.stdout.readline()` you can read it in again.

```
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

script_path = os.path.join('name_of_your_program.py')

p = Popen([sys.executable, '-u', script_path],
          stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)

while True:
    print("test-test-test-test")

    string = p.stdout.readline() 
    print(string[0:3])
```

**Output:**

```
test-test-test-test
b'tes'
test-test-test-test
b"b'T"
test-test-test-test
b'tes'
```

(It reads in binary so you have to convert it to a string.)

Comment: This just looks like what I needed , will give a try thanks