# How do i read from the command line with Python?

Tags: python, shell, command-line, operating-system

This code writes `google.de has address 216.239.34.117` to the shell

```
import os

os.system("host google.de")
```

Now i want to save the IP-Address into a string variable, but i can`t figure out how i read from the command line. Or is there even an easier way to get the IP-Adress to a variable?

Thanks and Greetings,
Alex

Comment: Maybe you are looking for argparse

Comment: This is not reading from command line! You want to redirect subprocess' stdout to your own program. I'd suggest using e.g. `subprocess.Popen` as it allows you to control stdin, stdout and stderr

Comment: I have been there before : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055963/catch-print-output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign output of os.system to a variable and prevent it from being displayed on the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503879/assign-output-of-os-system-to-a-variable-and-prevent-it-from-being-displayed-on)

Comment: @OzgurOz OcasoProtal I think that is what i'm searching for! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you use *socket* library instead of *os*?

```
import socket

host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('google.de')
print(host_ip)
```